# Magento helloworld tutorial

Tags: php, magento

We're working on Alan Storm's tutorial: [Magento Controller Dispatch and Hello World](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world) on Magento 1.5.0.0.

at the step:

> Clear your config cache, and load the following URL
> http://exmaple.com/helloworld/index/index

and it produces a page not found error, as follows:

> Whoops, our bad...
>
> The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
>
> - If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
> - If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

Two of us are working on this. One of us on a Linux platform, the second on Mac OS X 10.6.7. The same "page not found" error on both platforms. We both have double-checked each other's tutorial code by comparison to Alan's article. It seems that something is remiss in the tutorial code in that it would not work on two independent platforms.

What is the best way to move ahead with debugging something like this?

Comment: Which 404 page? (what's the wording on it) http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages

Comment: Shouldn't you replace exmaple.com by address of your computer (i.e., `http://localhost/helloworld/index/index`)?

Answer (score 3):

First check the module is active, at the very least it should appear in *System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Module's Output* or use Alan's [Module List](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/alanstorm/extension/6677/module_list).

Next, double check for typos in the controller class and pay particular attention to the case. In the config frontname should be `frontName` (a capital `N` is often overlooked).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , Double check your `/path/to/magento/app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml` , I had the codePool set to "community" and placed my extension in "local" directory this caused the 404 issue, when I changed the codePool value to "local" everything worked

Answer (score 0):

example.com (or exmaple.com as typo'd in the tutorial) is a placeholder link used in documents. You are supposed to replace it with your own hostname, i.e. if you are developing on a local webserver http://localhost/, like this: http://localhost/helloworld/index/index

Comment: The error page quoted is the standard Magento message and not what you get if you follow that link. It would suggest Seaquest only used "exmaple.com" for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled over the same problem and found the solution to be that **mod_rewrite has to be enabled on the server** for the URL given in the tutorial to work. Elsewise, it will work with the following URL as well:

```
http://exmaple.com/index.php/helloworld/index/index
```

Answer (score 0):

try by adding "index.php" in your url.

For example: http://example.com/index.php/helloworld/index/index

If you are done with this. Search some article to remove index.php from magento.

Answer (score 0):

I am on magento 1.8 and i fixed my 404 error by doing the following. inside Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml they tell you to put this code in "local" since i do not have a local folder i put mine into the community folder. Change the code to this and it will work. "community"